# Positioning fixed element over a floating one

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to position a fixed element over a floating one. 
For it, i am using the `z-index` property but it seems it is not working with fixed elements.

In this example I am trying to position the word `text` over the white floating box.
http://jsfiddle.net/imac/Pkrqw/1/

Is it possible to do what I am trying to?

These are the styles I'm applying:

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
}

.floatingBox{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:480px;
    height:80px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    left:80px;

    z-index:100;  /* LOWER THAN .text Z-INDEX*/
}
.text{
    display:inline;
    z-index:999; /* HIGHER THAN .floatingBox Z-INDEX*/
}
```

And this is the HTML for the example:

```
<div class="floatingBox"></div>
<div class="footer"> This is just a demo <div class="text">text</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give position to your `text` div for `z-index` to take effect. Just add:

```
.text{
    display:inline;
    z-index:999; /* HIGHER THAN .floating Z-INDEX*/
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it seems it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/imac/Pkrqw/5/

Comment: Please mention that next time :) I'll take a look

Comment: @Steve It seems it's chrome bug as it takes into account position `fixed` child elements with higher `z-index`, but not the outside ones. Another option would be to use `absolute` position instead `fixed`.

Comment: I will accept it as it seems there's no solution for it. Thanks.